# Merge meshes with different materials in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, merge, mesh

I have two separate meshes I want to merge with different materials using the combineMeshes function in unity.  When I combine the meshes though, the resulting mesh just uses the material of the first material.  How do I maintain the previous meshes in the new mesh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to do this is to modify the materials list of the new mesh.  Just make sure to set the variable in Combine Meshes to not merge submeshes, and if it maintains the submeshes as it should then it is simply a matter of setting the correct materials in the mesh's array.  I haven't tested this myself with combine meshes since I ended up going down a different route but I believe this should work.